# One word substitutions for number of days?

Tags: synonyms

Words exist to label periods of time - like **week** which represents 7 days and **fortnight** which is used for a 14-day period. Are there other such words used for certain numbers of consecutive days?

Comment: There is a companion website, ELL, on which to ask basic questions. I'd remove the 'fortnight used for 15 days' before you get downvoted.

Comment: in the UK, fortnight means 14 days, and I've been told it's not widely used in US English.

Comment: Just for fun, you could use a millicentury (about 36.5 days) :-)

Comment: I believe George R. R. Martin has done much to promote usage of 'fortnight' in modern English :)

Comment: Mykola, only in US English.  It has been commonplace in UK English for a long time (also in Australia, Ireland and several other Commonwealth countries)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps a different [counting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusive_counting#Inclusive_counting)?

Comment: Actually, in French and some other languages, a fortnight (or  equivalent) is 15 days. In Welsh, a week is 8 days: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight. Of course, we are discussing English language here; just an aside.

Comment: @iterums Perhaps a different website in that case? (See nxx's comment.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Fortnight** is used (or was used until now) for *14* days.

It is more tough with **year** and **month**, which stand for 365 or 366 and 29-31 days respectively (at least if they're solar ones). **Leap year** is 366 days. **Quarter** is 3 *months* and one fourth of a *year*.

Archaic **sennight** (sevennight) was just another word for *week*, as well as **hebdomad** (more facetious than archaic).

**Quarantine** is 40 days, though limited in its usage.

Meteorologists may call 5 days a **pentad**.

Catholics had **octave** for 8 days and still have **novena** for 9.