# Periods of days, weeks and months

Tags: american-english

In an application targeted to US users for stocks analysis, they can select the period used in the calculation and the idea is to differentiate between immediate available data vs aligned fractions of the year/month/week.

For example, if I say "Previous 3 months" and you look at it from February, the app should calculate from October-December and not November-January, I need the terms to describe these periods.

- Previous Day
- Previous Week (7 days)
- Previous Fortnight (14 days)
- Previous Bimester (2 months)
- Previous Trimester (3 months)
- Previous Quadrimester (4 months)
- Previous Semester (6 months)
- Previous Year

Are these terms used in the US? If not, are there alternatives?
Thanks

Comment: If you leave the actual duration in the selection screen, I do not see why using any word to describe it would matter...

Comment: Try https://books.google.com/ngrams with corpus = American English to compare theirs relative usages.  I suspect bi-/quadrimester will be rare.

Comment: @Skooba It has to represent a fraction of the year, if I say "last 3 months" and you look at it from February, the app should calculate from October-December and not November-January.

Comment: Only Day, Week, and Year are common in non-technical use in the US. Trimester and Semester are regularly used, but only to divide up pregnancies and school years, respectively. Fortnight is very rare (and probably will sound distinctly British or old-fashioned even to folks who know what it means) and I've never heard Bimester or Quadrimester used anywhere, ever (though they very well might be, in some technical area where I don't venture).

Comment: @k1eran Thank you, I am going to check that.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[One word substitutions for number of days?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128643)*

Comment: I've heard "Quarter" used frequently to describe a 3-month interval and have only heard "Trimester" used to describe a school year broken into 3 parts (4-months). I have never heard "Bimester" or "Quadrimester".

Comment: Sorry, you're not making sense.  Why would you say "previous" anything, to describe a "period"?  (But ditch everything but "day", "week", "month", and "year".)

Comment: [*Fortnight* and *semester* are equally common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fortnight%2Csemester%2Cquadrimester%2Ctrimester&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfortnight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csemester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrimester%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrimester%3B%2Cc0), but *quadrimester* is quite rare. Avoid these.

Comment: @TheIronCheek In the UK a _quarter_ tends to be a fixed period; usually one of Jan-Mar, Apr-May, Jun-Aug or Sep-Dec. If the same applies in the US  using _quarter_ to replace _trimester_ in the OP's application would cause confusion if it was being used in, say, July or October.

Comment: @HotLicks In stocks/commodities analysis, the high, low, open and close values changes a lot if you calculate them based on [the immediate available data vs aligning them to a fraction of the year](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379477/periods-of-days-weeks-and-months#comment892248_379477). This is easy in Brazil as we have those exact terms, but I'll use numbers and state in the manual how the calculation is done for the US version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I opted to follow [skooba comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379477/periods-of-days-weeks-and-months#comment892244_379477) and use month numbers instead. Most of the terms I showed before were either (archaic)accounting terms or the closest one I found... but it looks like it would be more confusing than just using month numbers.

Comment: I'd consider carefully whatever Google calendar or Apple  do, since I'm sure they've spent a fortune on this type of UI issue.